# How to detect which collision layer a KinematicBody is colliding with in Godot

Tags: game-physics, game-development, godot, gdscript

I would simply like to know how to detect which layer a KinematicBody is colliding with in code.

I have 4 layers:

Player

Roof

Ground

Wall

How can I use code to check if the player is colliding with the Ground layer? I am using move_and_slide() to move my player, so it would be best of their is a solution where I could use move_and_slide()'s collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what the `KinematicBody` collided with during the motion of `move_and_slide` or `move_and_slide_with_snap` using `get_slide_count` and `get_slide_collision`.

Something like this:

```
for index in get_slide_count():
    var collision := get_slide_collision(index)
    var collider:PhysicsBody = collision.collider
    if not is_instance_valid(collider):
        continue

    # …
```

Now, since you say "layer", I suppose we are talking of a `collision_layer`, so perhaps you can do something like this:

```
for index in get_slide_count():
    var collision := get_slide_collision(index)
    var collider:PhysicsBody = collision.collider
    if not is_instance_valid(collider):
        continue

    if collider.get_collision_layer_bit(3):
        # …
```

*Replace `3` with the number of the bit of the layer you want to check for.*

---

You can, of course, use other ways of filtering. Such as node groups:

```
    if collider.is_in_group("Ground"):
        # …
```

Class (requires setting a script with a `class_name Ground`):

```
    if collider is Ground:
        # …
```

Name:

```
    if collider.name == "Ground":
        # …
```

And so on.

---

By the way, if you are struggling with `is_on_floor`, first of all, check it after `move_and_slide` or `move_and_slide_with_snap`. And if you are getting intermittent results, try changing the physics engine to "GodotPhysics" on project settings under Physics -> 3D.

The work around to make `is_on_floor` work with "Bullet" is to make sure there is always a velocity against the floor. Which reminds me, there is other information in the collision you get from `get_slide_collision`, including the `normal`.